# Convert TIFF to PNG module object is not callable

Tags: python, pythonmagick

I am trying to convert TIFF to PNG using `PythonMagick` and this is the code

```
from PythonMagick import Image
from PIL import Image

sImage = 'MySample.tiff'
sOutput = 'MyOutput.png'
sCropped = 'Cropped.png'

def crop(img, image_path, coords, saved_location):
    Image(img).write(image_path)
    image_obj = Image.open(image_path)
    cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)
    cropped_image.save(saved_location)
    # cropped_image.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    crop(sImage, sOutput, (440, 145, 770, 195), sCropped)
```

I have encountered an error like that

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f77d54075818> in <module>
     14 
     15 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 16     crop(sImage, sOutput, (440, 145, 770, 195), sCropped)

<ipython-input-16-f77d54075818> in crop(img, image_path, coords, saved_location)
      7 
      8 def crop(img, image_path, coords, saved_location):
----> 9     Image(img).write(image_path)
     10     image_obj = Image.open(image_path)
     11     cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to fix such an error?

Comment: `Image(img).write(image_path)` what do you want to do here? I don't think you need PythonMagick. the standard PIL.Image module is enough

Comment: (note: the error occurs because you're trying to _call_ the `Image` module as a function)

Comment: using `PIL.Image module` gives me errors with some of the images I am dealing with.

Comment: I think the problem is `Image` from two different packages

Comment: With two `import`s importing the same thing like that, the second one wins and all references to `Image` will refer to that one.

Comment: @martineau Do you mean I can do without one of them and depend only one of them?

Comment: I don't know, perhaps. It looks like the only thing you're using PythonMagick for is to write the file, which you immediately read back into memory, Regardless, it seems like something you could easily test yourself.

Comment: I already tested and tried to comment out the PIL package but it seems Image in PythonMagick has no open attribute. No matter, renaming both images solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem but I welcome any ideas

```
from PythonMagick import Image as ImageA
from PIL import Image as ImageB

sImage = 'MySample.tiff'
sOutput = 'MyOutput.png'
sCropped = 'Cropped.png'

def crop(img, image_path, coords, saved_location):
    ImageA(img).write(image_path)
    image_obj = ImageB.open(image_path)
    cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)
    cropped_image.save(saved_location)

crop(sImage, sOutput, (440, 145, 770, 195), sCropped)
```